# Uniform sum distribution

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was wondering how to derive the probability density function for the sum of $n$ independent iid distributed random variables on the interval $[0,1]$. A formula for that is given on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformSumDistribution.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

but I still do not understand how to derive this "sum-formula" for the (pdf), may you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution of the individual distribution. You can prove the formula for the PDF of the Irwin-Hall distribution by induction on $n$, the number of variables.